# how can I make a simple form with GET method on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to do this very simple thing, I want to submit a post via `GET` method, but everytime I submit it, it redirects to my home page(with the parameters) .

If i try the `POST` method works, but I need the GET, any idea how to do this simple thing?

Thanks

Comment: are any of the fields empty when you submit?

Comment: no, all have information

Comment: can you post the string? also check your rewrite rules!